# Creating a circle following a pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I'm trying to come up with a new logo for my tireshop, and I'm trying to create a tire in Photoshop. I really like the outline of this one:
 [image: example]

How is a circle outline like this created? I know how to create a star with flat corners, but that just don't cut it. How can i make a custom circle outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, I would create a circle path that will be the outer edge of your tyre. Then create a triangular wedge shape and align this so that it crosses over the top of your circle path, like so:

[image: Step One]

Then, rotate and copy this wedge around the circle. Press R for the Rotate tool, and holding Alt, click the centre of the circle (it helps if you have Smart Guides turned on). This will bring up the Rotate dialog box — enter an angle number that divides evenly into 360. In this case, I've chosen 15, but feel free to experiment. Press Copy to make a copy (who'd have guessed?) — if you then press Ctrl-D (or Cmd-D) this will repeat the last command and add wedges around the circumference of your circle:

[image: Step Two]

Making sure that the circle is the bottom-most layer (it will be if you've followed these steps), select all paths, go to the Pathfinder tool and select 'Minus Front'. This will cut the wedge shapes from the circle:

[image: Step Three]

Finally, if you're using a later version of Illustrator, if you use the Direct Selection Tool with the path selected, you'll notice a load of small blue circles appear. Drag one of these and it will add rounded corners to each of the segments. And there you go!

[image: Step Four]

**EDIT:** I've just re-read the question, rather than the first answer, and realised you asked for this for Photoshop, not Illustrator. Oops! I'm going to leave this here as it's how I would go about it anyway — as with the previous answer, I would create the tyre in Illustrator and then import it into Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i would create the tire pattern in `illustrator` and import as a smart object.

If the pattern you have it what you want try just using the `magic wand` to select the white/grey part.  then press `Q` to go into quick mask and use the `brush` tool to paint the mask.  once you have the mask the way you want save as a `path`. there are many ways to get it done I would just use what you found and like to start.